# Creating Raphael SVG without onload

Tags: javascript, svg, charts, raphael

Iam fairly new to SVG and this is my first time trying svg with javascript. I am trying to create a collection of charts using Raphael SVG. In order to create these charts I need to create an SVG element dynamically. The problem here is that the javascript function to create the chart is being accessed from the html page where the data input for the charts is entered. So inorder to access the function (Charts();) I have not added an onload function. Due to this, the Raphael svg is not getting created as it needs a DOM element on which it is created. How do I fix this problem?

Charts.js is as follows:

```
var Charts = function Charts(config){

    var chart = this;


    chart.defaults = {
        .....
    };

    chart.Line = function(series, dataline){
    var newconfig = (config) ? mergeConfig(chart.defaults, config) : chart.defaults;
    return new KzSc(createSVG(newconfig, series, 'line'), newconfig, { series : series, name : 'line', dataline : dataline});
    }





    function createSVG(config, series, name){
        //create svg
    var chart_wrapper = document.getElementById(config.wrapperId);
    chart_wrapper.style.position = "relative";
    var SVGpaper = new Raphael(320, 200);
    chart_wrapper.appendChild(SVGpaper);
    var createSVGContainer = document.createElement("div");
    createSVGContainer.setAttribute('id',config.containerId);
    chart_wrapper.appendChild(createSVGContainer);

    }}
```

This gives the error 'Cannot read property of 'x'' in the rapahel script.

The html part contains the script which calls the function.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="charts.js"></script>
<script>
    var = (describe data for charts)
    new Charts(....);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="containerforsvg"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, if I add an onload or ready function i.e;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var Charts = ...
)}
```

Then it gives the error Uncaught ReferenceError: Charts is not defined

Comment: Not quite sure I follow your logic on why you can't it to onload. Can you give a simplified example of the part that you think won't work if your svg is created after onload ?

Comment: I can see the edit helps a bit, don't you want to call new Charts from within the .ready function ?